# how to create a new object from the sum of elements of an array of objects

Tags: javascript

I am doing a data manipulation practice with an array of objects, which I want to add income and expenses of all the objects of the array and return an object, I do the sum in a "correct" way but it is dirty and I would like to know If there is a cleaner way to do the code.
This is the array of objects:

```
const projects = [
  {
    amount: 26800,
    type: 'expense',
  },
  {
    amount: 2600,
    type: 'income',
  },
  {
    amount: 6890,
    type: 'expense',
  },
  {
    amount: 901800,
    type: 'expense',
  },
  ...
];
```

This my code javascript:

```
const dato = () => {
  let income = 0;
  let expense = 0;
  const total = projects.map((project) => {
    income += project.type === 'income' ? project.amount : 0;
    expense += project.type === 'expense' ? project.amount : 0;
    return {
      income,
      expense,
      byTotal: {
        total: income - expense,
      },
    };
  });

  console.log(total[total.length - 1]);
};
```

The object I want to create is the following.

```
{
  income: 3900000,
  expense: 2293600,
  byTotal: {
    total: 1606400,
  }
}
```

Comment: you can also use reduce

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce` instead of `map`, and use `Object.assign` to sum the amounts in an accumulator object:

```js
const projects = [{amount: 26800,type: 'expense',},{amount: 2600,type: 'income',},{amount: 6890,type: 'expense',},{amount: 901800,type: 'expense',},];

const dato = () => {
    const {income, expense} = projects.reduce(
        (acc, {type, amount}) => Object.assign(acc, {[type]: acc[type] + amount}),
        {income: 0, expense: 0}
    );
    const total = {income, expense, byTotal: {total: income - expense}};
    console.log(total);
};

dato();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```
const total = projects.reduce(
    (acc, cur) => {
        if (cur.type == 'income') acc.income += cur.amount;
        if (cur.type == 'expense') acc.expense += cur.amount;
        acc.byTotal.total += acc.income - acc.expense;
        return acc;
    },
    {
        income: 0,
        expense: 0,
        byTotal: {
            total: 0,
        },
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of a `reducer` by subtracting or adding the `amount` based on the type in one line:

```js
const projects = [{
    amount: 26800,
    type: 'expense',
  },
  {
    amount: 2600,
    type: 'income',
  },
  {
    amount: 6890,
    type: 'expense',
  },
  {
    amount: 901800,
    type: 'expense',
  }
];

const sum = projects.reduce(
  (amount, object) =>
  amount + (object.type === "expense" ? -object.amount : object.amount),
  0
);

console.log(sum)
```